# Run process using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, process

I'm trying to run a program that converts unaligned zip file to aligned zip file. To do that Google provides [zip align](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html) tool. It doesn't have GUI, so I'm trying to create C# WPF program.

I want to start that tool from my program, I tries various methods such as starting command prompt and run that tool using arguments. But it didn't work out.

And I used following method to start the process with arguments.

```
string genArgs = "f -4 C:\\Users\\Isuru\\OneDrive\\Freelancing\\DigitalClock\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\app-release-unaligned.apk outfile.apk";
string pathToFile = "C:\\Users\\Isuru\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\build-tools\\23.0.2\\zipalign.exe";
Process runProg = new Process();
try
{
    runProg.StartInfo.FileName = pathToFile;
    runProg.StartInfo.Arguments = genArgs;
    runProg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    runProg.Start();
    // start our event pumps
    runProg.BeginOutputReadLine();
    runProg.BeginErrorReadLine();
    runProg.WaitForExit();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Could not start program " + ex);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But then I get following error. Is there any other method?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[`Process.BeginOutputReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if `RedirectStandardOutput` is set to `false` which is the default value. If you want to capture the standard output then you have to redirct it, i.e. set `RedirectStandardOutput` to `true`:

```
runProg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

The same applies to `BeginErrorReadLine` and `RedirectStandardError`.

```
runProg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

Comment: I get the same error after changing the code. Please check the edit.

Comment: @Isuru there is nothing to check as you didn't edit the question.